# KeyError Pandas after merging and reshaping

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, keyerror

This code is from https://github.com/Sapphirine/BITCOIN-PRICE-PREDICTION-USING-SENTIMENT-ANALYSIS . It seems the key is in place:

```
print(merged.columns.tolist()) 
['Time', 'Sentiment', 'Price']



print (data.columns.tolist()) 
['Unnamed: 0', 'Time', 'Sentiment', 'Price']
```

but I keep getting KeyError: 'Sentiment' I also tried stripping spaces.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
values = datag['Price'].values.reshape(-1,1)
sentiment = datag['Sentiment'].values.reshape(-1,1)
values = values.astype('float32')
sentiment = sentiment.astype('float32')
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Ariel\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2441             try:
-> 2442                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2443             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5280)()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5126)()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20523)()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20477)()

KeyError: 'Sentiment'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-4b4b74484966> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
      2 values = datag['Price'].values.reshape(-1,1)
----> 3 sentiment = datag['Sentiment'].values.reshape(-1,1)
      4 values = values.astype('float32')
      5 sentiment = sentiment.astype('float32')

C:\Users\Ariel\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1962             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   1963         else:
-> 1964             return self._getitem_column(key)
   1965 
   1966     def _getitem_column(self, key):

C:\Users\Ariel\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   1969         # get column
   1970         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 1971             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   1972 
   1973         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

C:\Users\Ariel\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1643         res = cache.get(item)
   1644         if res is None:
-> 1645             values = self._data.get(item)
   1646             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1647             cache[item] = res

C:\Users\Ariel\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3588 
   3589             if not isnull(item):
-> 3590                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3591             else:
   3592                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

C:\Users\Ariel\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2442                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2443             except KeyError:
-> 2444                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2445 
   2446         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5280)()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5126)()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20523)()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20477)()

KeyError: 'Sentiment'
```

Comment: looks like you don't have column with name `Sentiment`

Comment: What is `datag` and how is it related to `merged` and `data`?

Comment: `datag`comes from `datag = data[['Price','Sentiment']].groupby(data['Price']).mean()`